# WepApi TaskCanceledException A task was canceled. httpClient

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, dotnet-httpclient

It was working good, but I made some changes in the api, adding more controllers nothing out of the place,  and then it stops working, always thrown an exception: "TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled" in the line GetAsync().result. I increase the timeout and infinitely stays loading.
The code controller APP who make a request to the controller API:

```
  public ActionResult Login(LoginM us)
    {
        try
        {
            cuentaM account = new cuentaM();
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            var result = client.GetAsync("http://localhost:26723/api/Login" + "?email=" + us.email + "&password=" + us.password).Result;
            if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                account = result.Content.ReadAsAsync<cuentaM>().Result;
            }

            Session["cuenta"] = account;
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;

        }
    }
```

The controller API code:

```
 public HttpResponseMessage Get(string email, string password)
    {
        try
        {
            using (elevationbEntities db = new elevationbEntities())
            {
                usuario user = db.usuarios.Where(m => m.email == email && m.password == password).SingleOrDefault();
                cuentaM account = new cuentaM();
                if (user != null)
                {
                    account = (from o in db.cuentas
                               join cu in db.cuentausuarios on o.idCuenta equals cu.idCuenta
                               join u in db.usuarios on cu.idUsuario equals u.idUsuario
                               where u.idUsuario == user.idUsuario
                               select new cuentaM {  idUsuario = user.idUsuario, idCuenta = o.idCuenta, CodigoUnico = o.CodigoUnico })
                               .FirstOrDefault();
                }
                else
                {
                    account.Error = "Wrong Password or Email";
                }

                HttpResponseMessage response;
                response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, account);
                return response;
            }
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException ex)
        {

            HttpResponseMessage response;
            response = Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex);
            return response;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Making blocking calls (`.Result`) on `HttpClinet`'s async API can cause deadlocks especially if being used asp.net MVC, which may have async operations being invoked when the blocking call was made.

Make the code async all the way through.

Also try to avoid creating an instance of `HttpClient` on every request. This can cause sockets to be exhausted.

```
private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginM us) {
    try {
        cuentaM account = new cuentaM();
        var url = "http://localhost:26723/api/Login" + "?email=" + us.email + "&password=" + us.password
        var result = await client.GetAsync(url);
        if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
            account = await result.Content.ReadAsAsync<cuentaM>();
        }

        Session["cuenta"] = account;
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be deadlocking by blocking on an async call, as described in [this article](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). Here's the problematic line:

```
account = result.Content.ReadAsAsync<cuentaM>().Result;
```

Change the method signature for `Login` to:

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginM us)
```

Then change the problematic line to use `await` instead of `.Result`:

```
account = await result.Content.ReadAsAsync<cuentaM>();
```